# MySQL migration error -1073741571

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

trying to migrate MS SQL to MySQL with MySQL Workbench but I keep on getting the error below, when it hits the first big table:

ERROR: Copy helper exited with an error: Worker exited with status -1073741571

I've tried Google no luck, tried migration on both the source and target servers no joy.

any ideas?

Comment: What log file says? Did you tried enable debug mode for copying data?

Comment: debug is on this is what it says: 18:40:04 [DB2][      copytable]: 9 - CVStBEGIN:`simdb_hirebywire`.`dbo_CV`:Copying 15 columns of 119695 rows from table [simdb_hirebywire].[dbo].[CV]
ERROR: Copy helper exited with an error: Worker exited with status -1073741819

Comment: Hmm this is not very helpful. Tell me what is your OS and how you setup your connection to source RDBMS? Which driver you used?

Comment: win 10 I use a system DNS to the RDBMS

Comment: Please take a look at this guide http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/ and check if you done everything as there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was that needs the input of the password of mysql admin (wasn't asked need to click on the "store in vault" button).